# typeorm select nested join relation fields

Tags: typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

typeorm is not giving nested join relations selected data while using getOne method

```
this.repo.createQueryBuilder("po")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("po.purchaseOrderItems","poi")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("poi.items","item")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("po.center","center")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("po.vendor","vendor")
    .where(data)
    .select([
        "po.id",
        "item.name",
    ])
    .getOne()
```

this gives reasult as

```
{
  id:number
}
```

expected output is

```
{
  id:number,
  purchaseOrderItems:[{
    items:{
     name:string
    }
  }]
}
```

same as if i execute

```
this.repo.createQueryBuilder("po")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("po.purchaseOrderItems","poi")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("poi.items","item")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("po.center","center")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("po.vendor","vendor")
    .where(data)
    .getOne()
```

for which result i get

```
{
  id:number,
  purchaseOrderItems:[{
    items:{
       name:string
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `select` you have to add associate relation column in the fields. You can try this

```
this.repo.createQueryBuilder("po")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("po.purchaseOrderItems","poi")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("poi.items","item")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("po.center","center")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("po.vendor","vendor")
    .where(data)
    .select([
        "po.id",
        "poi", //added
        "item.name",
    ])
    .getOne()
```

Comment: Thanks I figured it out prior to ur and but yes it's correct. Thanks.